# Why am I getting these undefined errors when I compile a C++ program in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gcc, c++, compiler, code-blocks

I have a C++ program that compiles and runs perfectly in Code Blocks. However when I try to compile it from the terminal using:

```
gcc -g main.cpp -o Main
```

I get a lot of undefined references:

[image]

And this is a screenshot of the program running in Code Blocks:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I didn't find the specific solution but I found a work around. Apparently the classes aren't being linked. So I put all the classes into the main file and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You should be compiling using `g++`, `gcc` compiles C programs. To install all required packages of `g++`, do `sudo apt-get install build-essential` on a terminal and then to compile your program, do `g++ -g main.cpp -o Main`.

Comment: I tried with the g++ and I'm still getting the same exact errors!

Answer (score 0):

#### You should use `g++` for C++ programs always!

That's because:

- [`gcc`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc/) is GNU C      Compiler
- [`g++`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/g++/) is GNU C++ Compiler

So they are different compilers and so they are different packages. The main differences:

1. `gcc` will compile: `*.c` / `*.cpp` files as C and C++ respectively.
2. `g++` will compile: `*.c` / `*.cpp` files, but they will all be treated as C++ files.
3. if you use `g++` to link the object files, it automatically links in the std C++ libraries (`gcc` does not do this).
4. `gcc` compiling C files has less predefined macros.
5. `gcc` compiling `*.cpp` and `g++` compiling `*.c` / `*.cpp` files has a few extra macros.

Source: [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172592/2353900)

Comment: I tried with the g++ and I'm still getting the same exact errors!